# Why does this serialization logic fail with 'unmatched serializable field(s) declared'?

Tags: java, serialization

A reproducible example:

```
package test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectStreamField;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class mySerializable implements Serializable {

    private static int f;
    private static int g;

    private static final ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields = {
            new ObjectStreamField("f", Integer.class),
            new ObjectStreamField("g", Integer.class),
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        save();

    }
    public static void save() {
        try {
             FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("config" + ".ser");
             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
             out.writeObject(new mySerializable());
             out.close();
             fileOut.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("save()" + ex.getLocalizedMessage());        }
    }
    public static int getF() {
        return f;
    }
    public static void setF(int f) {
        mySerializable.f = f;
    }
    public static int getG() {
        return g;
    }
    public static void setG(int g) {
        mySerializable.g = g;
    }
}
```

The program prints:
**save(): test.mySerializable; unmatched serializable field(s) declared**

Comment: `f` and `g` are static.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's the point of ObjectStreamField: am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: `static` and `Serializable` are two very different things.  At the end of the day, because you have no instance variables, there's really nothing to serialize.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two problems:

- `f` and `g` are `static`; static fields aren't serialized.
- They're also of type `int`, not `Integer`.

Make them non-static, and refer to them using `int.class`.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/FjwOdb)

Comment: Isn't the point of the ObjectStreamField array to allow static properties to be serialized?

Comment: What would it mean for a static field to be serialized? You serialize *instances*, not *classes*. Imagine static fields were serialized: if they are non-final, then deserializing an instance suddenly stomps on whatever value is there already; if they are final, you can't change their values anyway, so either the values are equal (so why serialize them?) or they are unequal (in which case you've not got the data you think you have). Serializing static fields just doesn't make sense.